# Does mutability change behaviour of namespace in case of 'from modulename import variable'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

If we update the class variable via instance, then a new instance variable gets created for that instance only. However if the class variable is mutable (say list), then making change to class variable via instance using append makes the change global across all instances.

Similarly, in case of `from modulename import x`, we know that if `x` is int/string then changing value of `x` in calling module is only visible in calling module and not globally. However, if `x` is mutable, then does mutability have any impact on behaviour with respect to namespace? For example,  does changing value of `x` in the calling module updates the value in the global namespace? Or something else?

Comment: No. And note, mutable and immutable values here don't really make a difference, immutable objects simply lack mutator methods.

Answer (score 2):

Python does not make a copy of an object on import. The `from module import foo` syntax simply assigns a specific object from the module to a name in your scope. Furthermore, a module is only loaded once, so any subsequent import would recover the same object as well.

Thus, if you import a mutable object and update it, this change is reflected everywhere that object has been imported, however that import took place. Keep in mind that this happens because the imported object and the module object are the same in memory.

### Example

Here is an example demonstrating that behaviour.

#### module.py

```
lst = []

def print_lst():
    print(lst)
```

#### main.py

```
from module import lst
from module import print_lst

# Print the list initially
print_lst()

# Append to the list in this scope
lst.append(1)

# Print the list from inside the module
print_lst()

# Importing the module again does not reload it
import module

# Proof that the list was not copied
print(module.lst is lst)
```

### Output

```
[]
[1]
True
```

Comment: Thanks. The question is about using 'from modulename import variable'. So in your example if we did 'from module import a', then any change made to 'a' in calling module will not have global impact. Right? Does this behaviour change if the variable was of a mutable type?

Comment: @variable There is no difference in the semantics between mutable and immutable objects, they behave *exactly the same* with respect to the import machinery, immutable values simply *lack mutator methods*

Comment: @variable It's the same idea, anything imported still lives in the module namespace. Python does not copy objects on import. See the new example.

Comment: In your example, the assignment is locally visbile in that main.py and doesnt impact valur of lst inside the module. Also, any subsequent import of module by another .py file will still see lst value as []. However if you had done 'import module1' in your code, then the append would be globally visible. Is this right?

Comment: @variable No because a module is loaded only once. Further imports do not reload the module. Unless you purposely delete the module by import sys, then whatever you do will lead to the same behaviour as above

Comment: I have edited the comment 'subsequent import of module by another .py file'

Comment: @variable If a thid file was to import the module, it would still not reload the module. The module is loaded only once. Thus, in a third file importing the module, you would see the changes having been done to lst

Comment: Please can you point me to a reference article that explains about this concept.

Comment: [Python's doc on import?](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: Do you mean '5.4.2. Submodules'?

Comment: This is just a suggestion. This is surely documented somewhere in there. Although the key points are that: modules are loaded once and objects are not copied on import. My above example encapsulate that, but feel free to find exactly where that is written in the doc. By example the fact that module are loaded only once is mentionned in [5.4.1](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#loaders)

Answer (score -2):

An old story. In short, when you import something, you get a copy into the current namespace. That's exactly the same as the following example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a # get a copy
b.append(4)
print(a) # [1, 2, 3, 4]

a = 1
b = a # get a copy
b = 2
print(a) # 1
```

Comment: You absolutely **do not get a copy of the object**, you created a new variable in a different namespace which refers to the same object, so to be clear, the object isn't copied

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You do get a copy. Or maybe some other term, but whatever, you now have a new reference. For some types like `int`, changing it won't influence the original one. For container types like `list`, you are changing the underlying heap instead of the reference itself. So it works. Well, anyway, I think my example is clear enough, don't understand why you disapprove.

Comment: reference != copy

Comment: @ruohola God, a copy of the reference. Should I have to be so specific?

Comment: @Sraw I think the wordind is important, because saying copy in this context really implies Python is somehow calling `copy(a)` which is implicitly what the question is about (and what some languages actually do on assignment). So you seem to understand correctly, but the wording is kind of off.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Honestly, I've never thought about it. Because as I said, this is an old story, I've answered this kind of question many many times. This time I don't want to be that specific as I see the OP is a guy with 1.2k reputation and 2 gold medals instead of a newcomer. He should be able to understand it. Well, I hope...